# Excel 2013 opens files slow in Windows 10 (when not in Safe Mode)

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, performance, windows-10, microsoft-excel-2013

This is a problem that has come up on Google and superuser in the past, although the solutions I have found haven't worked for me.

If I run Excel 2013, it opens instantly. If I am in Excel and open a file, the file opens instantly. But if Excel is closed, and I double-click a file, it will take a good 10 seconds before Excel actually opens.

The file in question is local to my machine.

What I have found so far:

- Running a repair install did not help.
- If I disable all non-Microsoft services on startup, and disable all Startup items (like Java, Steam), this has no effect, Excel still starts slow.
- I use multiple monitors with different DPIs. If I just use a single monitor, this has no effect.
- If I start Windows in safe mode, Excel opens quickly as expected (although it and all Office applications complain about my licensing, and mysteriously shut down).
- If I am logged into Windows normally, and open the file from the command line, this has no effect.
- If I am logged into Windows normally, and run the following from the command line, it opens quickly as expected:

  ```
  c:\program files\Microsoft office\office15\excel.exe path_to_my_file
  ```
- I am not well-versed in Sysinternals Process Monitor, but it looks like when opening from Explorer, that the action to actually open Excel doesn't occur for those 10 seconds, as if something in Explorer is holding up running the executable.

From all of this, it sounds like there is something running in Windows that is making the executing of the file delay before running Excel. I'm just not sure how to find it (such as what to look for in Process Monitor). Does anyone know what to do?

EDIT: If I go into Task Manager and close Explorer, and then launch the file from Task Manager, it opens immediately. Something is wrong with Explorer?...

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable [Cortana](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/getstarted-what-is-cortana). That worked for me.

Alternatively you can try with changing a value of the following key:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\Open\command]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.8\shell\Open\command]
```

To

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" "%1"
```